# Global constants used within (member) functions

Tags: function, constants, global

Is using global constants within (member) functions considered bad practice?  I personally don't feel comfortable doing this, though I cannot explain why. It just does not look right to have that global constant inside the body of the function.  Is it better to introduce a parameter in place of the constant instead (and default its value to that global constant)?  This is what I tend to do, and it does look better to me (*looks* better is all I can say though).  But after reading some posts below, I realize now that it would be nice to be able to override these constants for whatever reasons (like testing), and we all know that this really isn't feasible if that constant appears in many places in the function body.  How do others feel about this?  I use C++, but I figure this question is language-independent

But for some reason, I feel fine using global variables in a function, though I sometimes wonder if I should also introduce a parameter for this and default it to that global variable.  This inconsistency of mine makes me wonder about the whole thing.

Comment: What language are we talking about or is it just a general question? In any case, if you don't use global constants in functions, where *do* you use them?

Comment: No it's not bad practice at all. However, taking those variables in as parameters can enhance code reusability.

Comment: C++. But I figured this question is language-independent.  And I think I'm inquiring about member functionsin particular.

Comment: It's not bad practice per se, but it might depend on how you do it - I prefer `static const` to `#define` for instance.

Comment: For testability purposes, I like to make the constant overridable: introduce a getter for the value that, in the normal flow, returns the global constant. In an overriding class used for testing, you can set the "constant" to whatever you want. This is especially useful for very large timers or counters when you testing delays or loops.

Comment: Ah yes!  I think that is the reason why don't want to put in the constants.  I want them to be overridable.  Didn't realize that until I read your post.